# c# Asynchronous class?

Tags: c#, function, asynchronous, directory

I'm new in C# (I come from C) so I'm a bit confused with asynchronous operations.

I have a class that have all the "important" functions of my program, it download a file and add it to a folder, etc.

and then I have a WPF form (graphic interface), so when user select a folder it scan all the files in the folder and download a cover art for all music tracks.

I want to make a progress bar, obviously it must be asynchronous, and I don't know who to do this.

I think I must call the "important" functions asynchronous when the user click on the button

is there any good tutorial for making this? or could you tell me the basic steps?

Comment: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) component, you can follow this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx) in order to make your progress bar work.

Comment: Thank you I follow the tutorial (its fine) but I dont know how to initializa the background worker. I have a class App where all components are initialized, and then I have another class Interfaz where are all the events (button click, etc..). backgroundworker must be in App or in Interfaz?

Comment: The backgroundworker should be used in your Interfaz class where the button click and the progress bar are defined.

Comment: yeah, but im working on WPF and there is no backgroundworker in the toolbox so i need to instance it "manually". where i must put  this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;  etc...?

Comment: BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker(); and the rest of the code from your reply should be placed in MainWindowViewModel.cs

Comment: Im doing something wrong, i got an error, It says that I didnt control InvalidOperationException in public MainWindow() function, that function only calls InitializeComponent();  sorry for bad translation of the error :/

Comment: Please take more care when reviewing suggested edits, [such as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1154068); this is an obvious question being asked in the edit, and should have been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C#.Net =D

[TPL (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) is a collection of classes that help you with asynchronous programming and since you use WPF to display your data, I would also suggest you read about [MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained). It is a very important design pattern for applications with a user interface.

Enjoy the reading :D

And after you are done with it, maybe the following code sample helps you implement your asynchronous behaviour.

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisible, Converter=booleanVisibilityConverter}" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="100"/>
```

In MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
public MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool ProgressBarVisible {
        get { return progressBarVisible; }
        set { 
            progressBarVisible=value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProgressBarVisible");
        }
    }

    public void LoadImages() 
    {
        ProgressBarVisible = true;

        //your logic for downloading the images

        ProgressBarVisible = false;
    }

    public void DownloadImagesAsync()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(LoadImages);
    }
}
```